# GFCF/GPDI in Real GDP Calculations

Tags: gdp, investment

I'm trying to understand how GPDI / GFCF are used in the real GDP calculations (when compared to net investment). In both the US / Denmark, the real GDP numbers seem to directly GPDI / GFCF without factoring in depreciation. Am I missing something here?

(Example: https://www.bea.gov/sites/default/files/2020-05/gdp1q20_2nd_0.pdf, the GPDI row has values that far exceed the 1-2% net investment estimate for the US).

Comment: Related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14625